# Energy required for obtaining required mass of aluminium from alumina via electrolysis

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, electrolysis

How do I know how much energy I need to obtain 20 g alumunium from alumina with 5 V?

I calculated the quantity of electricity is 2.22 F.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Required energy $E$ can be found as a product between voltage $U,$ current $I$ and time $t$:

$$E = UIt\label{eqn:1}\tag{1}$$

Unknown multiplier $It$ can be found using [united Faraday law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_laws_of_electrolysis):

$$m = \frac{MIt}{zF}\quad\implies\quad It = \frac{mzF}{M}\label{eqn:2}\tag{2}$$

where $m$ is the mass of the substance liberated at the electrode; $M$ is the molar mass; $z$ is the number of electrons transferred per ion; $F$ is [Faraday constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_constant).
Considering aluminium is produced via [Hall–Héroult process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%E2%80%93H%C3%A9roult_process) or similar, at the cathode the following reaction takes place:

$$\ce{Al^3+ + 3 e− → Al}$$

and $z = 3.$
Plugging \eqref{eqn:2} into \eqref{eqn:1} allows to finally find the energy:

$$
\begin{align}
E &= \frac{mzUF}{M}\\
  &= \frac{\pu{20 g} × 3 × \pu{5 V} × \pu{96485.33 C mol-1}}{\pu{26.98 g mol-1}}\\
  &= \pu{1.07 MJ}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: With much respect, can you assist me to understand chemistry? Can i have your email or whatever platform, so i can ask simple chemistry question to you? Basically, i dont have privilege to ask many questions in this forum. @andselisk

Comment: @Lifeforbetter I prefer not to share my personal information and I don't do private teaching. If you have a question, the better way would be to ask *community* and post a new question. Also, please note this is not really a forum, but a Q&A site with somewhat restricted back-and-forth communication capabilities. In the meantime, I'd suggest to look at [Resources for learning Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry), or enroll in [free chemistry courses online](https://www.mooc-list.com/tags/chemistry).